# Complex YouTube search query

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I have to search in a subset of YouTube results. For example, the query should search for some song title that belongs to a set of artists. Is it possible to group expressions?
For example, I would like to find all videos titled *Vogue* by either *Madonna* or *Rihanna*. So the required query should like something like this:

```
(Madonna|Rihanna)+Vogue.
```

The problem with this query is that the results returned will include all the songs by Rihanna and Madonna and all the videos that have *Vogue* in the title. And this I don't want.
Is there any way to specify complex logical expression to YouTube search API?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into the same problem.

Comment: Nope. Sorry. Did not find a simple solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Just be more precise with your logic and use:

```
madonna+vogue|rihanna+vogue
```